# Message Queue in OpenStack Grizzly Architecture

Tags: openstack

In OpenStack Grizzly architecture, why Cinder is using the same message queue used by Nova? While other services such as Quantum is having its own message queue to communicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a answer from Ken on Linkedin,

> Hi Hermesh - I think you are referring to my diagram from the
>   OpenStack Summit. That diagram is probably a little inaccurate -- it
>   shows the most common deployment architecture than a true logical
>   architecture.
>
> As far as I know, Cinder doesn't need to communicate through AMQP with
>   Nova. I've updated my diagrams and explanation at [OpenStack Grizzly
>   Architecture Revisited](http://www.solinea.com/2013/06/15/openstack-grizzly-architecture-revisited/)